# javascript mongooose Protect data integrity in mongodb during an update

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

How can i protect data which i am not updating when i am doing an update.
I noticed when i have a mongodb schema like this

```
var SCHEMA1 = mongoose.Schema({
    full_name: String,
    other_fields : String//etc
    schema2_foreign_field:{
        type: Schema.Type.ObjectId,
        ref: 'schema2'
    },
    array_field:[{
        field1: String,
        field2: String
    }]
})
```

run an update operation like this

```
modelDetail.update({
    full_name: 'Bryant Smith'
},
{$set:{
    other_fields: 'Some string',
    schema2_foreign_field:'510a073b3b6 - idstring'
}},
{safe:true, upsert:true},
function(){

})
```

This update wipes out everything that is not been updated.
How can I only update fields I want to update and keep the rest of the fields intact

Answer (score 0):

Please check out below link, which might help you in this context.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/

and try it again by setting

> upsert:false

Answer (score 0):

Actually your problem is because of the `safe` flag.

I'm unsure why this behaviour happens but I'd recommend just getting rid of it.
It's a remnant from very old versions of mongodb that used to do unacknowledged writes by default. making this option not very useful in this day and age.